# How can I assign an unsigned integer to an enum in C++?

Tags: c++, enums, type-conversion

In a C++ library whose internals I'm rewriting I have some unsigned integer variables that I want to convert to enums:

```
enum InitType {
    INIT,
    NON_INIT
};
```

and I have a variable of this type:

```
InitType InitVar;
```

The library is called from another section that of the code whose variables are plain integers:

```
uint32_t UnsignedIntVar;
```

I want to assign the unsigned version that was passed from the caller to the libraries internal enum:

```
InitVar = UnsignedIntVar;
```

But the compiler doesn't like this:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'InitType'
```

What is the cleanest way to perform this conversion?

---

Here are some ideas that I had:

If the `enum` has only two values, I can do it like this:

```
    InitVar = UnsignedIntVar ? Init : NonInit;
```

This is a lot of writing anytime I want to make such an assignment.

If it has more values, I can create a translation table:

```
InitType Uint2InitTypeConv = {INIT_0, INIT_1, INIT_2...};
```

Where `INIT_x` are just the names of the enums.  Then I can translate using the table:

```
InitVar = Uint2InitTypeConv[UnsignedIntVar];
```

This seems pretty clean.  However, I figure I should be able to overload `operator=` for this, but I can't seem to be get that right.  That would easily encapsulate any other ugliness I can come up with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can convert to enums *explicitly*:

```
InitType i = InitType(UnsignedIntvar);
```

If the integer doesn't have a value that corresponds to a known enum value, that is your problem.

A typical case where this is perfectly acceptable is a looping over enums:

```
enum ESomething { Default = 0, Something, SomeOtherThing };
for (int i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
{
  ESomething e = ESomething(i);
  // do something with "e"
}
```

Comment: Please change function-style cast to `static_cast`.

Comment: @aschepler: Think of it as a constructor call if you like :-)

Comment: @NathanFellman: You mean if you assign an unspecified value? Well, any part of your program that depends on your enum having a well-defined value may behave surprisingly. Note that you can achieve the same problem, though, by default-initializing an enum that has no zero: `enum ESomething { A = 1, B = 2 }; ESomething e;` You just have to be careful in general.

Comment: Sometimes I believe that `enum` were meant for undefined behavior. The complete absence of check is very surprising for novices, and still manages to catch experts anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
InitVar = UnsignedIntVar ? Init : NonInit;
```

> This is a lot of writing anytime I want to make such an assignment.

Yes, but since the *meaning* of a `uint32_t` differs from that of your `enum`, I would do it anyway. As they say in the Python community, "explicit is better than implicit". I wouldn't do a cast, and the table approach suffers from the drawback that you'd have to enumerate all `uint32_t` values to get full coverage, which would be practically impossible.

Why not introduce a function with an appropriate name to do the conversion? Something like `InitType init_type(uint32_t)`, implemented as a `switch`?

Comment: That is true, except that the external variable happens to have the same meaning.  I simply don't have the bandwidth to convert all instances of the external variable to the new enum at this time.